# How to enable log in administrator password?

Tags: login, password, administrator

I have enabled my administrative password but when I start my computer and just click on administrator it login in without asking for a password. I want it to be that whenever I start my computer it asks me for password (for the administrator account) before logging in.

Answer (score 1):

To get started, go to Ubuntu Options at the top right corner and select ‘System Settings..’

[image]

Next, click on ‘User Accounts’ to continue.

[image]

Then unlock the settings to make changes. Only an administrator or root user can unlock.

[image]

After unlocking , change the ‘Automatic Login’ to OFF

[image]

Or your can just run the commands below to open lightdm.conf file.

```
sudo -i gedit /etc/lightdm/lightdm.conf
```

[image]

Then remove the line as highlighted below and save the file.

[image]

[Source...](http://www.liberiangeek.net/2012/11/turn-off-disable-automatic-logon-in-ubuntu-12-10-quantal-quetzal/)